# IntelliJ Idea git messes up repositories. How to avoid?

Tags: intellij-idea

The IntelliJ IDEA Version control view shows two separate git repositories in one window, which I do not like. I could have 10 modules and each could have something shown in local changes, but I would like to **focus just on one project** (git repository) per commit. Same about log window - I would like just one project (git repository) shown. Is this possible with IntelliJ IDEA? To understand better what I mean you could imagine Eclipse and E-Git tool.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I get your pain point right, you want to group changes by directory (which is the same as git repository). To do it there is a Group By icon on the left panel of your screenshot (7th from the top) which allows to group the changes in different ways:

[image]

IntelliJ's docs: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/version-control-tool-window-local-changes-tab.html#d8971ff1